# llseek return ESPIPE when calling zcat all.tgz | ./cycletee

Tags: c, linux, bash, pipe, zcat

I modified GNU `tee` to `cycletee` [Source Code](https://github.com/vls/cycletee/blob/master/cycletee.c) (You can download the binary from https://github.com/vls/cycletee/tree/master/bin)

What it does can be explained by the following example:

```
seq 10 | cycletee 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
cat 1.txt // prints 1, 4, 7, 10
cat 2.txt // prints 2, 5, 8
cat 3.txt // prints 3, 6, 9
```

---

Then there is a `all.tgz` (See **Appendix** for building script)

`all.tgz` has three text file and totally 9000000 lines.

Everything is fine. Like:

```
seq 10000000 | ./cycletee 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt

zcat all.tgz | tee 1.txt > /dev/null

zcat all.tgz | tail // got 9000000 at the last line
```

except calling:

```
zcat all.tgz | ./cycletee 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

**when it reads the No.3000000 line, it exits.**

strace it I got this message and it exited:

```
_llseek(2, 0, 0xffbec3d0, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
```

**Question**

- Anyone can point out the problem of my source code?
- Any debugging technique to figure out the problem will be appreciated. I don't know how to use `gdb` in this situation.

**Appendix**

- `all.tgz` can be built by this Python sciprt https://gist.github.com/1500742
- Environment: Ubuntu 10.04 32bit, CentOS 5.4 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source:

```
read:
    buffer[0] = '\0';
    ptr = fgets(buffer, (int) sizeof buffer, stdin);
    if(NULL == ptr) {
        if(ferror(stdin)) {
            error (0, errno, "%s", _("standard input"));
            ok = false;
        }
        flag_break = true;
        break;
    }
    bytes_read = strlen(buffer);


      if (bytes_read < 0 && errno == EINTR)
      {
          flag_continue = true;
          backup_i = i;
          break;
      }
      if (bytes_read <= 0) {
          flag_break = true;
          break;
      }

    if (descriptors[0]
            && fwrite(buffer, bytes_read, 1, descriptors[0]) != 1)
            {
                error (0, errno, "%s", files[0]);
                descriptors[0] = NULL;
                ok = false;
            }
 ...
```

I don't think this will work on binary input (input that contains NULs).
[ Given the signedness of bytes_read, I have the strong suspicion that fread() has been replaced by fgets() + strlen(); ] This may or may not be the cause of the PIPE error, but it looks very wrong.

Comment: You're right. `zcat` did output some binary data when jump to next file. I use `fgets` + `memchr` to determine bytes have read. It runs well

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `llseek` or `ftell` on a pipe or socket, they are not seekable files.

You could use a debugger like `gdb` (it is really worth learning to use it; and GDB is very well [documented](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/documentation/)), and e.g. put a breakpoint on `_llseek`

You could also use `strace` or `ltrace`